# Weil + Perfekt (+nicht)

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause, negation, perfect-tense

I have a question regarding the use of *nicht* in a sentence with *weil* and perfekt.
Which one of the two sentences is correct?

> 1. Ich habe die Prüfung nicht bestanden, weil ich nicht studiert habe.
> 2. Ich habe die Prüfung nicht bestanden, weil ich studiert nicht habe.

Of course I can avoid this problem by using *denn*, but I want to know how to deal with this.

Comment: The first variant is correct, the second is wrong. It makes no sense to negate an auxiliary, because it has no meaning of its own.

Comment: That rationale *sounds* reasonable but isn't. The same syntax rules apply to modal + full verbs, even though it **is** conceivable to negate just the modality of an action: "Ich wollte nicht aussteigen, ich musste."

Comment: You actually don't use "studiert" very often like that. You rather say "weil ich nicht gelernt habe".

Comment: No, you can make the same mistake when using "denn": "Ich habe nicht bestanden, denn ich nicht habe gelernt". To avoid this mistake in both cases, you can remember to ask yourself "denn ich habe *was*?" oder "weil ich *was* habe?". The answer would be "*nicht gelernt*.".

Comment: _@JohnDoe_ _"Of course I can avoid this problem by using "denn""_ What do you mean in particular?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar are you kidding? OP knows that relative clauses do not need inverted word order (for whatever reason). Why don't you?

Comment: @vectory Are *you* kidding? My comment refers to the last sentence where he says he could avoid *this problem* (the misplaced *nicht*) using *denn* instead of *weil* - and all I'm saying is that he can not. He could make the same mistake.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar that is not literally the same mistake, because it requires another mistake first. Never show wrong examples, you haven't learned?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 is correct. "Nicht" comes before the verb in sub-clauses (where the verb is in end position).